# Wrong alignment with p-carousel PrimeNG

Tags: html, angular, carousel, primeng

I'm writting some code using Angular PrimeNG and I got a problem using p-carousel. The thing is as you can see the tittle is not well aligned in center, is a little bit up from where it needs to be.

[image]

This is my code, hope somebody could help, thanks a lot!

```
<p-carousel [value]='dateHistory' [numVisible]='1' [numScroll]='1' [circular]='true' (onPage)='pageChanged($event.page)'
            [showIndicators]=false [page]='page'>
  <ng-template let-date pTemplate='item'>
    <div class='flex justify-content-center align-items-center my-2'> {{ date.month }} - {{ date.year }}</div>
  </ng-template>
</p-carousel>

<div class='col-12 xl:col-3'>
  <p-card header='Money Flow' styleClass='border-round-3xl' subheader='Your Monthly Income & Expenses data'>
    <p-chart [data]='pieData' [options]='pieOptions' height='300px' type='doughnut'></p-chart>
  </p-card>
</div>
```